# Android Fragment not showing up in my application

Tags: android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android

I have a strange issue with my Fragment, I get no errors at runtime (I'm using Android Studio v8.7 and the Gradle compiles just fine) but when my app runs on my phone it's now showing up, it looks like an empty Activity.

Activity.class

```
package android.bignerdranch.com.criminalintent;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class CrimeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);

        // These are Fragments from the app.v4 package, it's needed to make the app compatible with API < 11
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = new Fragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Fragment.class

```
package android.bignerdranch.com.criminalintent;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitleField;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckbox;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container, false);

        mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              mCrime.setTitle(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
        mDateButton.setEnabled(false);

        mSolvedCheckbox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
        mSolvedCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCrime = new Crime();
    }
}
```

Activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_title_label"
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_title_hint" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_details_label"
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/crime_solved_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction and tell me what could solve my issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok i found the errors, I was instantiating the wrong Fragment.
Instead of

```
if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = new Fragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
```

It should be

```
if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = new CrimeFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
```